# Why Mistake - when simulate mouse in dotnetbrowser?

Tags: c#, wpf, dotnetbrowser

But when build - The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this in first browser.MouseMove(x, y)

```c#
public MainWindow()
{
    // Initialize WPF Application UI.

    InitializeComponent();

    // Create WPF BrowserView component.
    browser = BrowserFactory.Create();

    browserView = new WPFBrowserView(browser);
    // Embed BrowserView component into main layout.
    mainLayout.Children.Add(browserView);
    browser.FinishLoadingFrameEvent += delegate(object sender, FinishLoadingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsMainFrame)
        {
            int x = 100;
            int y = 10;
            browser.MouseMove(x, y);
        }
    };

    browserView.Browser.LoadURL("http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: Because the code inside the event handler is running in a background thread, from a background thread you cannot access UI components directly, you need to wrap the code with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (if you are using WPF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your code inside Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

```
 if (e.IsMainFrame)
 {
      int x = 100;
      int y = 10;
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action( ()=> {
          browser.MouseMove(x, y);
       }
 }
```